# Entity Framework assigns ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on a program using a SQL Server database. Using PUT/POST, I'm adding elements to the database. I run some code on the data, and then delete them afterwards. The issue now is, that when I add new data, the data added gets added with an increasingly high id number, rather than starting from 0.

I searched around, and found something that I thought would work, which is adding the below line above the Id. This, however, doesn't work, and I'm still getting an increasingly large Id number, when put into the database.

Is there a workaround for this?

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public virtual int Id { get; set; }

public int ProducedkW { get; set; }
public int ConsumedkW { get; set; }

public string Type { get; set; }
public int DifferencekW { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well, yeah? That's the point of the identity column isn't it? It's an automatically increasing column?

Comment: This is the intended functionality. Don't worry about restarting the id, it's completely unnecessary concern.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, please tag accordingly (SQL is just a *language*)

Comment: Oh, I see. A few of my classmates have written code which looks directly at the id, assuming there will only ever be 45 different id's, which is correct, but they don't have the value 0-44. Is there any way to overwrite this, so their code complies with the database? Or put differently, can I force the id to be 0-44?

Comment: Your comment confuses me. Is there already data in the database? Or is it starting out empty and you're adding all the data through EF and you want to add new rows starting with a given ID?

Comment: Why do you actually care about the Ids? If you care about them, it probably means they aren't system Ids, and should be considered 'business keys', on which you have control.

Comment: If the id's are being hard coded in C# your classmates are probably doing it wrong unless you have *very* specific assignment. There are ways to reset the id's but if you have to do that it *often means a design problem* imo.

Comment: @AdamV The database gets cleared in the start of the program. Once it's cleared, new data is added - this is where the 'issue' arises, that any new data added, despite the database being cleared, still has a higher and higher id.

Comment: If you by _clearing the database_ delete the rows in the table then the state to generate the unique ID doesn't get reset and the ID's will continue to increase. However, if you delete the table or the entire database then this state is lost and the ID will start at 1 once you recreate the table. However, the fact that you want to control the generated ID's is surprising. Are you using the wrong type of ID or haven't you fully understood the purpose of a unique database generated ID?

Comment: @Emil, as stated in the previous comments, the id increments its value every time a new record is inserted to the table, even when past records are deleted, which is the expected behavior. Can you please clearly explain how that is problem in your application?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways i can think of:

1. Truncate table instead of deleting the records It may throw exception in case it's referenced as foreign key in some other table.
2. Run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table name> ON`
    on  sql server, basically it then allows you to enter values explicitly in identity column. But keep in mind , you will have to set id in your code.
   But keep in mind , you may lost uniqueness of your column, you willhave to ensure it progamatically in your code then.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comments, it sounds as though you do not want an IDENTITY column, but rather a regular INT column.

By removing the IDENTITY attribute of the column you are then free to control the IDs yourself.  Just set the ID field on your Entity and when you call DbContext.SaveChanges it will take care of it.